# Ansible - how to keep only 3 release

Tags: ansible

I have a VPS sever where I deploy frequently releases and the dir structure is that I have a current dir, what is a symlink to an actual release under a releases dir. 
How can I achieve, that only X ( in my case 3) releases stay in the releases dir, the rest can be deleted, to spare free HDD and because I don't need them any more.
This setup is what capifony uses.

Answer (score 7):

Something along this lines should work, where **bin** would be your symlinked directory :

```
- name: Set timestamp
  set_fact: release_timestamp="{{ansible_date_time.epoch}}"

- name: Deploy code from repository
  action: git repo={{repo_url}} dest={{app_dir}}/releases/{{release_timestamp}} remote={{repo_remote}} version={{branch}}

- name: Create symlink to bin folder
  file: src={{app_dir}}/releases/{{release_timestamp}}  dest={{app_dir}}/bin state=link

- name: List old releases and clean them up
  shell: "ls -t {{app_dir}}/releases | tail -n +{{releases_to_keep + 1}}"
  register: ls_output

- file: name={{app_dir}}/releases/{{ item }} state=absent
  with_items: ls_output.stdout_lines
```

If you want to do rollback:

```
- name: Find the previous release
    shell: "ls -t {{app_dir}}/releases | head -2 | tail -1"
    register: ls_output

- name: Create symlink to previous release folder
    file: src={{app_dir}}/releases/{{item}}  dest={{app_dir}}/bin state=link
    with_items: ls_output.stdout_lines
```

Comment: I came across your suggestion. Thank you for that one. One thing to add: Variables in `with_items` should be surrounded by brackets `{{}}`. `with_items: {{ ls_output.stdout_lines }}`

Answer (score 5):

This is an old topic but I think this answer will be helpful.

```
- name: Find all directories in releases folder
  find:
    paths="{{ app_dir }}/{{ releases }}"
    file_type=directory
  register: dirs

- name: Only last three releases
  file:
    path="{{ item.path }}"
    state=absent
  with_items:
    - "{{ (dirs.files | sort(attribute='ctime'))[:-3] }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a bit off-topic, but it will give you a place to start:

There is an Ansible role in the galaxy specifically pointed at replacing Capistrano/Capifony. With an example for a Symfony2 project even :-)

- https://galaxy.ansible.com/list#/roles/732

Example usage:

- https://github.com/SweetLakePHP/SweetLakePHP/blob/master/ansible/deploy.yml

To answer your question more specifically:

The loop required to clean the releases folder would be either a shell script or a composition of Ansible tasks (saving `ls` output, sorting and removing). To make this a smoother process, we decided to place this logic in an Ansible module. This module is used in the project_deploy role linked above. But if you prefer to wrote your own role, the module was extracted and placed in ot's own galaxy role:

- https://galaxy.ansible.com/list#/roles/2266

Finally, if you're interested in a deeper look at why we came to the current construction:

- http://future500.nl/articles/2014/07/thoughts-on-deploying-with-ansible/